# How to call asynchronously 3 groups of 2 chained $http.get requests

Tags: angularjs

Dear Stackoverflow's members,

I need to call asynchronously 3 groups of 2 chained $http.get requests.
For each group of chained requests, I need to get the id of an attribute then to do a 2nd $http.get request to get data from the id.
When all group requests are done, I need to resolve all got data.
Below is the function I developed.

```
function initChartData(starttime, endtime) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var attrURLs = [baseURL + '|Attribute1',
        baseURL + '|Attribute2',
        baseURL + '|Attribute3'
    ];

    var promises = [];
    var attrNames = [];
    var dateFormat = 'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm';

    angular.forEach(attrURLs, function (url) {
        promises.push(
            // 1. First $http.get request: Get the ID of the attribute
            $http.get(url)
                .then(function (responses) {
                    // 2. Second $http.get request: Get the data from the ID
                    var data = responses.data;                        
                    return $http.get(data.Links.GetData + '?starttime=' + $filter('date')(starttime, dateFormat) + '&endtime=' + sEndTime);
                })
            );
    });

    $q.all(promises)
        .then(function (responses) {
            var data = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
                data.push(responses[i].data.data });
            }
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

What do you think about my function ? Are the 3 groups of the 2 chained $http.get requests called asynchronously ? Or are the 2nd $http.get requests called when all the 1st $http.get requests are done ?

Thanks,
Best regards,
Etienne

Comment: Your code should work. It's full of anti-patterns so could be improved, but it will work. Check this version http://plnkr.co/edit/19OZBI4rM3ZBFoiEIhwP?p=info

Comment: Hello dfsq thank you very much for replying to my message and for your correction. So, in my app, I replaced all `$q.defer()` when I could. I also read some web page about the promises. Thanks.